# Android 3D Carousel integration to my application in android

Tags: android, button, carousel

I am new to Android Programming.I integrate the Android 3D Carousel app into my application using following link
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/146145/Android-3D-Carousel
It works fine.
But my requirement is instead of I need to place the multiple buttons as one view as shown in attached screen shot.

Please suggest me how can I proceed?
Thanks in
advance[image]

Comment: you can have look at this for your [carousel](https://code.google.com/p/carousel-layout-android/)

Comment: In place of imageviews Can I place the Views with multiple buttons?If yes,How is it.Please help me

Comment: yes you can. [Download](https://github.com/strider2023/Carousel-Android) and see adapter class.

Comment: Hi, I'm an Android beginner and I'm interested in knowing how you managed to integrate this 3d carousel inside another Android project. If it's not too long, I'd be glad to get a few guidelines about how to do it, because I tried to integrate this kind of carousel to my app, and failed already.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

write your adapter like this

```
package com.example.uitest;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class  CarouselAdapter  extends BaseAdapter {

    private ArrayList<String> array;
    private Activity mContext;

    LayoutInflater inflator=null;
    public CarouselAdapter(Activity context,ArrayList<String>array) {
        mContext = context;
        this.array=array;
    }

    /*public void setData(ArrayList<Integer> data) {
        mData = data;
    }*/

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return array.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int pos) {
        return array.get(pos);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int pos) {
        return pos;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int arg0, View convertview, ViewGroup arg2) {
        if(convertview==null)
        {
            ViewHolder holder=new ViewHolder();
            convertview=mContext.getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.carousellayout,null);
            holder.btn1=(Button)convertview.findViewById(R.id.button1);
            holder.btn2=(Button)convertview.findViewById(R.id.button2);
            holder.btn3=(Button)convertview.findViewById(R.id.button3);
            holder.btn4=(Button)convertview.findViewById(R.id.button4);
            convertview.setTag(holder);     
        }
        ViewHolder hold=(ViewHolder)convertview.getTag();
        hold.btn1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Toast.makeText(mContext, "Clicked on button 1", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
        hold.btn2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Toast.makeText(mContext, "Clicked on button 2", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
        hold.btn3.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Toast.makeText(mContext, "Clicked on button 3", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
        hold.btn4.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Toast.makeText(mContext, "Clicked on button 4", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });

        return convertview;
    }

    static class ViewHolder
    {
        Button btn1,btn2,btn3,btn4;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Before asking anything have you tried anything first. Can you post the code you tried and from there we can move forward